# Poisson Distribution Mean Over Multiple Time Periods

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Given a Poisson distribution with rate $\lambda$ events per single time unit - is it correct to deduce that in $t$ time units the mean number of events is $\lambda t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote by $X_i$ the number of events in the $i$-th time unit, by assumption $X_i \sim \operatorname{Pois}(\lambda)$.
You are asking for $\mathbf E \sum_{i = 1}^t X_i$ which, by linearity of expectation is equal to $\sum_{i = 1}^t \mathbf E X_i = t \lambda$, so the expected number of events in $t$ units of time is indeed $t\lambda$.

Note however that if you are also interested in the *distribution* of $X = \sum_{i = 1}^t X_i$ then you will have to make some assumptions on the joint distribution of $\left( X_1, \dots, X_t \right)$. For example if the $X_i$ are *independent* then $X \sim \operatorname{Pois}(t\lambda)$.